# SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint slowing down the Sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

I have a little game that requires a SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint and it all works, except for one the fact that the joint while it is active which is 10 seconds slows down the sprite by what seems half the speed of the sprite without the joint active.

I have tried, restitution, density and even velocity, but of them worked. Could someone please guide me in the right direction. Nothing I find on here or Google seems to work.

Image of Spaceship without Shield:
[image: Image of Spaceship without Shield]

Image of Spaceship with Shield:
[image: Image of Spaceship with Shield]

Image of Spaceship with Shield and showPhysics = true:
[image: Image of Spaceship with Shield and showPhysics = true]

```
func activateShield() {

    let shield1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-1")
    let shieldImages = [shield1, SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-2"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-3"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-4"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-5"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-6")]

    let animateShield = SKAction.animate(with: shieldImages, timePerFrame: 0.10)
    let animateRepeatShield = SKAction.repeatForever(animateShield)

    shield = SKSpriteNode(texture: shield1)
    shield.name = "ShieldActive"
    shield.setScale(2.5)
    shield.position = player.position
    shield.zPosition = 3
    shield.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: shield.size)
    shield.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    shield.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ShieldActive
    shield.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy
    shield.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy | PhysicsCategories.LifePu
    shield.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    shield.physicsBody!.density = 0
    self.addChild(shield)
    shield.run(animateRepeatShield)

    let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: player.physicsBody!, bodyB:shield.physicsBody!, anchor:player.position)
    self.physicsWorld.add(joint)

    //turns off the shield in between 5-10 seconds
    shield.run(.wait(forDuration: 10, withRange: 0)) {
        self.shield.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously, are there people out there with nothing better to do than down voting. I asked a perfectly good question, after trying everything I could find. I am a new coder and instead of any help of comment I get an instant down vote. What is happening to the world...

I detailed what the issues is, what I have tired, added the code and images. What more can I do? I would really like to know.

Comment: not sure about the down vote but I can tell you that someone voted to close the question based on "Unclear what you are asking" might give you some insight into why the down vote.

Comment: What's unclear about it, I detailed it as much as possible, it says exactly what the problem is the code is there, the explanation is there and there are even two screenshots.

And how about instead of voting to close a question talking to me and asking me if I can be more detailed, or where the unclearaty might be.

Comment: I've been there! I remember first starting on this site. It felt like I was holding my hands out begging for people to not downvote and maybe throw some love my way in the way of an upvote. I will tell you that taking an aggressive or angry tone will get you plenty of downvotes though.

Comment: I am not trying to be aggressive or angry. I am just looking for some help with a problem that has been bugging me for months. Maybe you can help me?

Comment: I would recommend showing an image with the physics boundaries turned on. GameViewController -> ```view.showPhysics = true``` but don't leave that on because it'll slow down your game, but it's perfect for testing

Comment: You mean show a screenshot here?

Comment: yes add another screenshot with the showPhysics turned on and with the shield on

Comment: Done, it has 2 physics bodies active when the shield is active. The reason for this is because for some reason the shield physics body wouldn't collect any powerups.

Comment: why did you choose to add it as a joint? does it move independently from the ship?

Comment: It should move with the ship while active. Isn’t a joint the way to do that?

Comment: nope. a joint is where to physicsBodies connect and can swivel (like a human joint) . BTW I never ever create dynamic physics bodies it always slows the game down.

Comment: just add the shield and physics as a child of the player and it'll move with the player

Comment: The game itself runs fine. It’s only the ship that moves slower when the shield is on. Most likly cause two physicsbodies on top of each other have double the weight.

Comment: Not sure how else I would add a shoeld to the ship that would be stuck to the ships movement while active!?

Comment: Thanks you are correct, I removed the physics joint and added the shield as a second sprite over the player position and added it to the touches moved with the same settings as the player ship and it works perfect, thank you very much for you help. I added it as an answer, if you could so this issue is green ticked accept the answer, thanks so much for guiding me in the right direction on this one.

Comment: perfect!, glad it worked out and you figured out the answer on your own! you can check your answer as correct

Comment: Ah ok cool, need to wait until tomorrow to do so :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the help of @Ron by removing the PhysicsJoint altogether and then adding the shield.position.x += amountDragged same way it was done for the Spaceship and it worked perfectly.

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocation(in: self)

        let amountDragged = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x

        if currentGameState == gameState.inGame{
        player.position.x += amountDragged
        shield.position.x += amountDragged
        }

        if player.position.x > gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2{
            player.position.x = gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2
        }

        if player.position.x < gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2{
            player.position.x = gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2
        }

        if shield.position.x > gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2{
            shield.position.x = gameArea.maxX - player.size.width/2
        }

        if shield.position.x < gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2{
            shield.position.x = gameArea.minX + player.size.width/2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't add it on the player? like "player.addChild(shield)"

Comment: Already done dude thanks. This peoblem long sorted. On to new problems